# Bootstrap theme - add or remove classes in $navbar_classes

Tags: theming

I'm using the bootstrap theme, by default in page.tpl.php the nav bar is outputted like so:

```
<header id="navbar" role="banner" class="<?php print $navbar_classes; ?>">
```

Where can I edit the $navbar_classes variable called in the header tag so I can add or remove classes?

Comment: for what purpose do you want to add new classes?

Comment: I want the nav bar to be full width, which by default it isn't.

Comment: You will have to use the hierarchy of classes start from body tag, to access it an d use '!important' in in css style.

Comment: you can also read that  [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2450603)

Answer (score 3):

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      //add news class
      $vars['navbar_classes_array'][] = 'new-class';
      //remove class
      unset($vars['navbar_classes_array'][0]);
      // you need change value 0 to value you want remove class
      // Default
      // 0  'navbar', 1 => 'container', 2 => 'navbar-default'

}
```

You can do it with

1. Override file page.tpl.php. You can copy file page.tpl.php in bootstrap/theme/system/page.tpl.php to new your subtheme and edit it. It is right way.
2. Or you can use function hook_preprocess_page(). You can write code in file template.php of your subtheme. That way you don't need change file page.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `template.php` file of your current active theme and apply this code;

   ```
   <?php        
      function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
        $vars['nav_menu'] = str_replace('class="navbar-nav"', 'class="myclass"',           
        menu_tree('navigation'));
      }
   ?>
   ```
2. Now Open `page.tpl.php` file and you can print `$nav_menu` variable to add extra class in `<header>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on MrD's very good answer, I added a little extra to make the code a little less breakable.

In your template.php file for your subtheme, create the following hook.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    //adds container-fluid class 
    $vars['navbar_classes_array'][] = 'container-fluid';
    //removes class based on array value ('container' in this case)
       if(($key = array_search('container', $vars['navbar_classes_array']) !== false)) {
         unset($vars['navbar_classes_array'][$key]);
       }
 }
```